# Determine if object/embed is forbidden?

Tags: javascript, html, object, embed

You might know HN, but you maybe also do not like the fact of clicking around in many tabs/going back and forward. I thought about making some page on which both webpage and links from HN are. So I made this: http://goodfrontpage.com/direct

But there are 2 Problems:
First: How to determine if a page doesn't allow in it's http-headers to open it in something like this:

```
<iframe class="webpage" src="{{post.url}}" ></iframe>
```

or this:

```
<object class="webpage" data="http://asfasfasfa.com" >
<embed class="webpage" src="http://asfasffvasf.com" > </embed> 
Error: Webpage not accessible!
</object>
```

This is true for pages like github.com, eff.org or youtube.com

Second: Is there any possibility to fetch the sites in a different way allowing me to display all pages?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to embed a webpage within another one then you should use the `iframe` element:

```
<iframe src="http://asfasffvasf.com"/>
```

You can style this like any other block element, and set an explicit width and height.

---

Some pages ask browsers not to include them within iframes (using the `X-Frame-Options` [header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Frame-Options#Frame-Options)). I don't think there's an easy way to solve this on the client side, but you could create a simple backend or proxy to request the page you want and return the content. This gets round the `iframe` restriction because you're now including content from your own domain.

This does have a couple of security issues to be aware of:

- You've now made a backend which can be used to download any page on the Internet. There's a denial of service vulnerability if someone makes lots of requests to download huge pages.
- The pages you're including will no longer be restricted by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Scripts on those pages will be able to interact with everything on the parent page. This may be a problem if you plan on creating login functionality in the future.

Comment: For me that works exactly in the same way as my solution, but the problem is: Some pages (youtube, github, eff) don't allow me to present their page like that...in another page. You have some idea to catch that error? /Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for `iframe` property.It specifies an inline frame.

```
An inline frame is used to embed another document within the current HTML document.

<iframe src="http://asfasfasfa.com"></iframe>
```